# Android studio java.exe finished with non-zero exit value 3

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have pass through non-zero exit value 1,2, related to multidex issue, but now I am getting non-zero exit value 3.

Studio Message :

```
Information:Gradle: Executing tasks: [:emoticons_lib_proj:assembleDebug, :myProject_Developement:assembleDebug]
Information:5/27/2015 5:56 PM - Compilation completed with 1 error and 0 warnings in 5m 58s 77ms
Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':myProject_Developement:dexDebug'.
```

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 3

I hope someone might have faced the issue and fixed. kindly let me know where I am misleading,

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I'm stuck here too.

Comment: @dvc, I read your comment now,
first of all update sdk, what I remember for that, it was being resolving with restart studio, but not appreciating for me too, 
I hope after updating your setup, you can easily resolve the issue

Answer (score 16):

When your project contains large number of classes, android studio will throw out `non-zero exit value 3` error.

To solve the error, add this in `build.gradle` file and sync project with gradle.

```
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol 'javaMaxHeapSize'.
Probably does not work the latest build tools/gradle

Answer (score 7):

FIXED SOLUTION: Increased the HEAP size to 2g or 4g.

```
android {
    defaultConfig {}

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    packagingOptions {
    }

    buildTypes {
    } }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue almost every day, and I always get rid of it by clearing and rebuilding the project. The worst case is restarting Android Studio.

Comment: agreed, but this wont be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it seems to happen when running low on memory. I run Android Studio on a Windows 7 with 8 GB RAM, and every time the total RAM usage gets near 6 GB I get the same error code or a different one ("java.exe finished with non-zero exit value 1").

Closing some or all other programs (such as Internet browser, Android emulator) always solve the problem for me.

Comment: I also sometime got value 1 exit code, but this closing other applications seems not the right solution.

Answer (score -2):

I fixed my issue with:
android{
dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}
try will make fix even you issue. I hope so..