# android.app.AppOpsManager what's this?

Tags: android, google-plus

During the compilation of my Android app, a google+ login test application I came across the following error (see logcat message). I provide the manifest and gradle configuration files, and the app source in Java for reference.

Can anyone help me make sense of this problem?

logcat message:

```
I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.app.Notification$Builder.setLocalOnly, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza
W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 196: Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;.setLocalOnly (Z)Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;
D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x00c2
I/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: access denied from Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil; to field Landroid/app/Notification;.extras
W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve instance field 13
D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x54 at 0x00e1
E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza
W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 19 (Landroid/app/AppOpsManager;) in Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;
```

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. run app
2. press login button(com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton)
3. then bring on Login Activity then occur error

manifest.xml

```
<application android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
......
 <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
......
/>
```

gradle.build

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.test.app"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    //https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html
    //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29756188/java-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-2-android-gradle
    //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29033800/noclassdeffounderror-below-sdk-21
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
}
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
//http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32205938/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-android-support-v4-view-layoutinflatercompathc-i
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
//Google+ login
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
//ZXing Library
compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.0.2@aar'
compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0'
//Joda-time
compile 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.8.2'
//
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.0.+'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.0.+'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.2.3'

compile 'com.kakao.sdk:kakaolink:1.1.2'
compile 'com.kakao.sdk:usermgmt:1.1.2'
//glide
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
}
```

Login.java Activity

```
public class Login extends TroubleoActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{
    final   static  private     int                 RC_SIGN_IN          = 0;
    final   static  private     String              TAG                 = "Login";
                    private     GoogleApiClient     mGoogleApiClient;
                    private     ConnectionResult    mConnectionResult;
                    private     boolean             mIntentInProgress;
                    private     boolean             mSignInClicked;
                    private     int                 PROFILE_PIC_SIZE    = 400;

                    private     SignInButton        btnSignIn;
                    private     ImageView           imgProfilePic;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        btnSignIn       = (SignInButton)    findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_in);
        imgProfilePic   = (ImageView)       findViewById(R.id.imgProfilePic);

        //google api client initialize
        GoogleApiClient.Builder     builder     = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this);
        builder.addConnectionCallbacks(this);
        builder.addOnConnectionFailedListener(this);
        builder.addApi(Plus.API);
        builder.addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN);

        mGoogleApiClient    = builder.build();


    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                mSignInClicked = false;
            }
            mIntentInProgress = false;

            if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        mSignInClicked = false;
        Toast.makeText(this, "User is connected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        // Get user's information
        getProfileInformation();

        // Update the UI after signin
        updateUI(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        updateUI(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        if (!connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(connectionResult.getErrorCode(), this, 0).show();
                return;
            }

            if (!mIntentInProgress) {
                // Store the ConnectionResult for later usage
                mConnectionResult = connectionResult;

                if (mSignInClicked) {
                    // The user has already clicked 'sign-in' so we attempt to
                    // resolve all
                    // errors until the user is signed in, or they cancel.
                    resolveSignInError();
                }
            }
    }
    private void updateUI(boolean isSignedIn) {
        if (isSignedIn) {
            btnSignIn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //btnSignOut.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //btnRevokeAccess.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //llProfileLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            btnSignIn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //btnSignOut.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //btnRevokeAccess.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //llProfileLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
    private void signInWithGplus() {
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
            mSignInClicked = true;
            resolveSignInError();
        }
    }
    private void resolveSignInError() {
        if (mConnectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                mIntentInProgress = true;
                mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, RC_SIGN_IN);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                mIntentInProgress = false;
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }
    private void getProfileInformation() {
        try {
            if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
                Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi
                        .getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
                String personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
                String personPhotoUrl = currentPerson.getImage().getUrl();
                String personGooglePlusProfile = currentPerson.getUrl();
                String email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);

                Log.e(TAG, "Name: " + personName + ", plusProfile: " + personGooglePlusProfile + ", email: " + email + ", Image: " + personPhotoUrl);

                //txtName.setText(personName);
                //txtEmail.setText(email);

                // by default the profile url gives 50x50 px image only
                // we can replace the value with whatever dimension we want by
                // replacing sz=X
                personPhotoUrl = personPhotoUrl.substring(0,
                        personPhotoUrl.length() - 2)
                        + PROFILE_PIC_SIZE;

                new LoadProfileImage(imgProfilePic).execute(personPhotoUrl);

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Person information is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private class LoadProfileImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        ImageView bmImage;

        public LoadProfileImage(ImageView bmImage) {
            this.bmImage = bmImage;
        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String urldisplay = urls[0];
            Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
            try {
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mIcon11;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "logcat message" -- those messages are perfectly normal. They result from code being loaded that has references to classes that are from newer versions of Android than you are running your app on. If your app is crashing, then you need to use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace that is associated with your error. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks your fast comment! OK I'll got digging more!!

Comment: Make sure you have this permissions in your Manifest. <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />.  Try to debug the flow and then find out where the problem is actually or Post some more relevant logs.